# How to use the plus sign process of css selectors in LESS?

Tags: css, less

Is there a more efficient way to write the following CSS in LESS format, or is this it?

```
li:first-child {
    border-right: solid 0.188em #da291c;
    padding: 0 2em 0 0;
}

li:first-child + li {
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}

li:first-child + li + li {
    padding: 0 2em 0 0;
    border-right: solid 0.188em #da291c;
    margin-left: 21%;
}

li:first-child + li + li + li {
    padding: 0 0 0 2em;
}
```

Comment: You could further complicate it like [this](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22li%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%26%3Afirst-child%2C%20%26%3Afirst-child%20%2B%20%26%20%2B%20%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20border-right%3A%20solid%200.188em%20%23da291c%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20padding%3A%200%202em%200%200%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%26%3Afirst-child%20%2B%20%26%20%2B%20%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20margin-left%3A%2021%25%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%26%3Afirst-child%20%2B%20%26%2C%20%26%3Afirst-child%20%2B%20%26%20%2B%20%26%20%2B%20%26%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20padding%3A%200%200%200%202em%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) but I wouldn't recommend using either this or any Less `&` stuff. What you have is as short as Less (with selector grouping done) and is more readable than using the `&` stuff. I'd also recommend using `nth-child` if you aren't looking to support IE8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `&` to refer to the parent selector:

```
li:first-child {
    border-right: solid 0.188em #da291c;
    padding: 0 2em 0 0;

    & + li {
        padding: 0 0 0 2em;

        & + li {
            padding: 0 2em 0 0;
            border-right: solid 0.188em #da291c;
            margin-left: 21%;

            & + li {
                padding: 0 0 0 2em;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use `:nth-child`, it might be more appropriate for what you are trying to do, but check browser support http://caniuse.com

Comment: Just FYI, in the case of the adjacent sibling selector, you don't actually need the `&`, just `+ [selector]` will do